# Please help me using for loop in PHP

Tags: php

I want to use a loop to iterate through my array, calling my function to print out all of these messages. I have to somehow keep track of what number person im on. -- im using PHP

```
<?php
$name_array = array('pon', 'zi', 'pol', 'et');

function name_person($name, $number) {
    echo $name . ' is person #' . $number . ' ';
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $counter = 1;
    while ($counter <=4) {
        name_person( $name_array[$i], $counter);
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

my output should be:

```
pon is person #1, zi is person #2, pol is person #3, et is person #4
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: what you get right now ??

Comment: you don't need a while loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$name_array = array('pon', 'zi', 'pol', 'et');

function name_person($name, $number) {
    echo $name . ' is person #' . $number . ' ';
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    name_person( $name_array[$i], $i + 1);
}
```

Comment: check your loop ..its run five times..only four  data value in array there...so it's give error.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to apply a user supplied function to every member of an array.

Try this code.

```
$name_array = array('pon', 'zi', 'pol', 'et');

//remove 0 index from array (optional)
$name_array = array_filter(array_merge(array(0), $name_array));

function name_person($name, $number) {
    echo $name . ' is person #' . $number . ' ';
}
//apply a user supplied function to every member of an array
array_walk($name_array, 'name_person');
```

Output:

```
pon is person #1 zi is person #2 pol is person #3 et is person #4
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a nested `while` loop within `for` loop.
2. `for` loop should run from `0` to `<4` instead of `<=4`.
3. Lose the `$counter` variable and just use `$i+1` instead.

So it should be:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
     name_person( $name_array[$i], $i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for exact output try this:

```
$name_array = array('pon', 'zi', 'pol', 'et');

function name_person($name, $number) {
    echo $name . ' is person #' . $number;
}

foreach($name_array as $k=>$v) {
    name_person( $v, $k+1).(($k==sizeof($name_array)-1)?'':', ');
}
```